# mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE

Tags: mysql

When i tried to login to mySql from command line it gives me `mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
<username>@<username>-`error

how should i resolved this with out log into MySQL?

Comment: link from stackexchange check it -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165366/186356

Comment: @onkarI can't login to mysql then how should i execute the suggested command in that link ?

Answer (score 6):

This issue can be solved by making the following substitutions:

```
sql_mode = '[…]'
```

to be replaced with

```
sql-mode = ''
```

that is to say, by removing
the value of sql-mode directive in most cases as
per the value indicated in the question.

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

according to [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual > 5.1.11 Server SQL Modes > Setting the SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting)

Comment: Unbelievable! :)

Comment: This solved my problem! 